# Maya python: find bright spots in light texture in hdri and get the 3d coordinates

Tags: python, image-processing, vector, maya, nuke

This is my first time posting here. I hope someone can guide me to resolve my question.

In Maya,
Is there a way to get the 3d coordinates of the bright spots on the Hdri texture on Dome light. And extract those coordinates?

Can we do this in Nuke?
In Nuke, can we find the 2d coordinates of the brightest spots of an image and convert to 3d coordinates. Any help on this. Would be incredible!

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In NUKE, if you import a 3D scene there, you can use a `CurveTool` node with the ***MaxLumaData*** tool to determine the brightest pixel of the shader's speculars, and a `PointsTo3D` node to generate 3D axis based on the position of the 2D point.

[image]

Camera must be animated, of course.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me @andy.
I shall give this a go and revert back :)

Comment: i tried this and this does give me some translation values! Thats awesome!
Is there a way to get the rotation values and to get it re created in Maya itself?

Comment: Of course, but in Maya you need a "heavy" scripting for that.